# update-initramfs does not fully create initrd for new kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, dpkg, initramfs

I seem to be having a bizarre problem installing a new custom kernel. `update-initramfs` fails during `dpkg -i` with:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.7-hardened1-test1
find: ‘/tmp/user/0/mkinitramfs_gHxWMQ/lib/modules/5.15.7-hardened1-test1/kernel’: No such file or directory
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.7-hardened1-r7
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.7-hardened1-r7
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.7-hardened1-test1
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.7-hardened1-test1
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-10-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-10-amd64
done
```

The `r7` kernel builds and installs perfectly fine, but the `test1` installs with a `find: ‘/tmp/user/0/mkinitramfs_gHxWMQ/lib/modules/5.15.7-hardened1-test1/kernel’: No such file or directory` error. The only difference between the .configs is:

```
29c29
< CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-r7"
---
> CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-test1"
39c39
< CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP=y
---
> # CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP is not set
45c45
< # CONFIG_KERNEL_ZSTD is not set
---
> CONFIG_KERNEL_ZSTD=y
787c787
< # CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD is not set
---
> CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y
802,803c802,803
< CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ=y
< # CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_ZSTD is not set
---
> # CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ is not set
> CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_ZSTD=y
```

I even tried a slightly newer kernel (5.15.27) and older (5.10.104) with the same results. Trying to boot into the kernel drops the boot to a `initramfs` prompt (without USB keyboard functionality) after failing to find the root LVM.

The initrd images also have very different sizes for the minimal changes made:

```
9.7M initrd.img-5.15.7-hardened1-r7 (working)
9.1M initrd.img-5.15.7-hardened1-test1 (broke)
```

Doing a diff between the two with `lsinitrd` produces this, suggesting that the initrd does indeed lack a huge number of modules.

```
346,399c346
< 5.15.7-hardened1-r7
< kernel
< crypto
< async_tx
< async_memcpy.ko.xz
< async_pq.ko.xz
< async_raid6_recov.ko.xz
< async_tx.ko.xz
< async_xor.ko.xz
< xor.ko.xz
< drivers
< ata
< ahci.ko.xz
< libahci.ko.xz
< hid
< hid-generic.ko.xz
< hid.ko.xz
< usbhid
< usbhid.ko.xz
< usbkbd.ko.xz
< input
< keyboard
< atkbd.ko.xz
< mouse
< psmouse.ko.xz
< serio
< serio_raw.ko.xz
< md
< dm-bufio.ko.xz
< dm-crypt.ko.xz
< dm-log.ko.xz
< dm-mirror.ko.xz
< dm-raid.ko.xz
< dm-region-hash.ko.xz
< dm-snapshot.ko.xz
< linear.ko.xz
< multipath.ko.xz
< raid0.ko.xz
< raid10.ko.xz
< raid1.ko.xz
< raid456.ko.xz
< vfio
< pci
< vfio-pci-core.ko.xz
< vfio-pci.ko.xz
< vfio_iommu_type1.ko.xz
< vfio.ko.xz
< vfio_virqfd.ko.xz
< lib
< raid6
< raid6_pq.ko.xz
< virt
< lib
< irqbypass.ko.xz
---
> 5.15.7-hardened1-test1
```

Anyone seen this before? I found one results through google but a solution was never provided.

I'm running Devuan Chimaera (Debian 11 base) with: initramfs-tools=0.140 & dpkg=1.20.9

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Debian with kernel 5.16.17.
Disabling modules compression fixes the problem (you should set CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_NONE=y). It's possible, compressions different to ZSTD also work, but I have not checked.